# Twilio JS - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isSupported' of 'require(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, requirejs, twilio, twilio-php

I want to use twilio programmable video in a web application built on elgg engine.

I have registered twilio-sdk by following code

```
    elgg_define_js('twilio-sdk', [
        'deps' => array('jquery'),
        'exports' => 'twilio-sdk',
        'src' => "//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.7.1/twilio-video.min.js"
    ]);
```

and loading it via following code, according to the [twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/build-js-video-application-recommendations-and-best-practices#browser-support)

```
define(function (require) {
var elgg = require("elgg"),
    $ = require('jquery');
const { isSupported } = require('twilio-sdk');
if (isSupported) {
    // Set up your video app.
    console.log('This browser supports twilio-video.js.');
} else {
    console.error('This browser is not supported by twilio-video.js.');
}   
});
```

But I am getting the following error in console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isSupported' of 'require(...)' as it is undefined.
```

How to move proceed, can someone help as there are only very few tutorials available with twilio v2 sdk

Comment: check what this line is returning: const { isSupported } = require('twilio-sdk'); remove the destructuring and see the object. By the error you post, the property isSupported does not exists in the object.

Comment: @F.bernal: As i am loading the sdk from twilio servers, i wont be able to make modifications to the source file. I can see isSupported in the source file.